# Using angularjs expression to check boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

reading on [ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) attribute I realize we can use [angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) to determine wether a checkbox is checked or not.

I have images and dates. I want to make a table representing which image is active at a specific date. this [sql fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnvj6koq/4/) should help you understand what I mean.

In the fiddle, the four checkboxes are checked, but one of them (the one corresponding to the first image and the 'feb' date) should not be checked, since 'feb' is not in the dates of the first image (see the `$scope` definition below)

My problem is that the expression `date = image.dates` in the `ng-checked` attribute always return true, hence the four checked checkboxes.

**What expression could I use to verify that a specific date is in the image's defined dates?**

I can change the data model, so if it would be easier to have the dates of a specific image as an array rather than a string please go ahead.

view

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;"></td>
            <td style="width:35px;" ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="image in images">
            <td>{{image.name}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
                <input ng-checked="date = image.dates" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

app

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.images = [
        {name:'Image 1',dates:'jan'},
        {name:'Image 2',dates:'jan,feb'}
    ];
    $scope.dates = [
        "jan",
        "feb"
    ];
}
```

Comment: `image.dates.indexOf(date) > -1` should do the trick.  Also, you're using an assignment operator (`=`) in the expression, instead of a comparison (`==`)

Comment: oh my bad. That's why it was alright true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check if the dates contains the date expression.

Something like this:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="image in images">
        <td>{{image.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
            <input ng-checked="image.dates.indexOf(date) > -1" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```